# How can I understand that the user pressed which keyword?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I am coding a terminal like Linux terminal with C under Linux OS and I need to quit program when the user presses ctrl+D keywords. But I don't know how to understand that the user pressed these keywords. Thanks for your helping.

I'm getting inputs with fgets()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl+D is end-of-file. In that case, `fgets()` will return a null pointer.

So, your program's main loop can probably look something like this:

```
char buffer[2000];
const char* input = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
while (input) {
    do_something_with(input);
    input = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
}
```

Note that this only works for simple buffered input.  For information on lower-level keyboard handling, check out http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html

Comment: Yes CTRL + D is finishing my program. my problem is solved temporarily. but I think I will need keyword controls in future. It maybe CTRL+{A,B,...}. Can I understand the user's actions on keyboard.

Comment: Ctrl-D is not end-of-file. Ctrl-D is only the default setting of the VEOF c_cc array member of the `termios` structure, and VEOF is not end-of-file but pending-tty-buffer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example, how to read individual keypresses from a terminal keyboard:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(void){
  struct termios save,raw;
  tcgetattr(0,&save);
  cfmakeraw(&raw); tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&raw);
  unsigned char ch;
  do{
    read(0,&ch,1);
    if( ch<32 ) printf("read: Ctrl+%c (%i)\r\n",ch+'@',ch);
    else        printf("read: '%c' (%i)\r\n",ch,ch);
  }while(ch!='q');
  tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&save);
}
```

Better to know how a terminal sends keystrokes before you start using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) to handle terminal I/O.